# validation code not working direct redirect to action path

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

this is html from

```
   <form action="http://localhost/own/import.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">

      <input type="file" name="xmlfile" id="file1">

      <input type="file" name="uploaded_image" id="file2">

   <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" style="margin:0 0 0 150px;">
```

this is java script file

```
function getExt(filename) {
  var dot_pos = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (dot_pos == -1) {
     return "";
  }
    return filename.substr(dot_pos + 1).toLowerCase();
 }

function validate_ext() {
var filename = document.getElementById("file1").value;
var filename2 = document.getElementById("file2").value;
var ext = getExt(filename);
var ext2 = getExt(filename2);

if (filename != "") {
    if (!(ext == "xml")) {
       alert("Please upload XML file format only");
       return false;
    }
}

 if (filename2 != "") {
    if (!((ext2 == "jpg") || (ext2 == "jpeg") || (ext2 == "png"))) {
            alert("Please upload jpg, jpeg, png file format only");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
  }

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(validate_ext);
    alert("test");
});
```

i also share code here also http://jsfiddle.net/vikastyagi87/XugLp/18/

​

Comment: ...and the question/problem is?

Comment: Are you able to call validate_ext() ?

Comment: without check validation form submitted this action http://localhost/own/import.php

Comment: you missed hash symbol $('#submit')

Comment: thanks mini i forgot $('#submit') this one also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did mistake following line

```
if (filename != "") {
if (!(ext == "xml")) {
   alert("Please upload XML file format only");
   return false;
   }
}

if (filename2 != "") {
if (!((ext2 == "jpg") || (ext2 == "jpeg") || (ext2 == "png"))) {
        alert("Please upload jpg, jpeg, png file format only");
        return false;
    }
}
```

and but after change now it's working

```
if (!(ext == "xml")) {
   alert("Please upload XML file format only");
   return false;
}


if (!((ext2 == "jpg") || (ext2 == "jpeg") || (ext2 == "png"))) {
        alert("Please upload jpg, jpeg, png file format only");
        return false;
    }
```

here is working code http://jsfiddle.net/vikastyagi87/XugLp/29/

Answer (score 1):

filename can be undefined
You should try:

```
if (filename != undefined && filename.length > 0)
```

You forgot #

```
$('#submit').click(validate_ext);
```

Why did you write

```
if (!(ext == "xml"))
```

Instead of

```
if (ext.toUpperCase() != "XML")
```

!= simpler than !(==)
and 
your filename extensions can contain upper case characters